# How do I calculate the number of cases where at least one of four variables is true?

Tags: variables, statistics, spss

I hope you're doing well!

I've got four dummy variables in SPSS and am trying to work out what the syntax would be to calculate the number of cases where at least one of the four variables = 1 (meaning it's true). I believe the mathematical equation for this is:

A + B + C + D - (AB + AC + AD + BC + BD + CD) + (ABC + ABD + ACD + BCD) - ABCD
(where each letter represents a variable)

I could be wrong though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to create a new variable that will identify the rows where either of the variables A, B, C or D has the value 1.
This can be done in a few simple ways in SPSS syntax. Each of the following lines will result with variable `NewVar` having value 1 where the condition is met:

```
compute NewVar=(sum(A,B,C,D)>0).
```

OR

```
compute NewVar=any(1,A,B,C,D).
```

OR

```
compute NewVar=(A or B or C or D).
```

NOTE - the second and third solutions assume no missing values in A,B,C,D - those would need to be worked around if they exist.

Now that we've got a variable identifying the lines we want to count, we can now count them, like this for example:

```
FREQUENCIES VARIABLES=NewVar.
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks so much for your quick reply! Apologies, I don't think I explained myself very well so just to clarify, I'm after a way to work out the number of cases where at least one variable applies. For example, say A = lives in a house, B = is employed, C = likes salad. I want to calculate the number of cases in the sample where at least one of these things is true (as well as exclude any overlap, for instance if one person in the sample lives in a house and is employed, to not double count them).

Comment: OK, so you just need another step to do the actual counting - I'll add that to my answer